# How to copy Android Studio project to remote Git (NOT GitHub) server

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I can't find instructions for how to copy an Android Studio project from my Mac to a remote Git (NOT GitHub) server.

This doesn't seem like it should be hard but I have searched for hours and can't find anything specific.

A step-by-step guide would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps below works for any Jetbrains based platforms like Intellij IDEA, Android studio, PHPStorm, etc. It also works for any git platform **(including GitHub)**

You can use the following steps to push your code to a remote Git repository:

- Goto VCS in the menu bar.
- select "Enable version control integration."
- choose "Git"(not GitHub) and press ok.

Then you can see a Version control tab near android monitor.

- Open version control tab, go to local changes, and add all unversioned files to VCS. (Either right click on unversioned files and click add all, or click browse, select all, and click plus sign to add all to VCS)
- Commit changes (Ctrl+K)
- Push changes. (Ctrl+Shift+K)
- define remote URL
- enter username and password.
- click on push.

Comment: Thank you. However I don't immediately see how to "add all unversioned files to VCS". It says I have just the file vcs.xml in the Default Local Changes, plus in Unversioned Files, 4 directories and 1,835 files. What do I do?

Comment: View the unversioned files, select all and click on the plus sign. Or right click on the selected files and click add to VCS

Comment: On my version of Android Studio (2.3.3 Mac), the green plus sign at the left edge of the window (repeated on the Contextual Menu) says it will make a New Changelist. That doesn't sound like what I want. There is a Contextual Submenu: Git -> Add (which also has a green plus sign!). Do you think that's what I want? Very confusing.

Comment: OK, I tried the Contextual Submenu Git -> Add, then when I tried to Commit the changes, it would not let me check the box for the unversioned files (all 1,835 of them). vcs.xml was the only file it was going to commit. I canceled it. See what I mean about 'this shouldn't be so hard'?

Comment: I notice on the VCS menu there is a command to Import into Version Control -> Create Git Repository... . Is this of any use? When I select it, it asks me to Select Directory where the new Git repository will be created, and it pre-selects the src/main/res/layout folder, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Looks like you messed up. Maybe you added your files to a different change list. From the version control tab, delete other changelists except default. Also before you make any other mess, make sure you copy your src dir to a different location as a backup. It would be easier to help if you can provide the screenshot of the version control tab.

Comment: The project was just created and I have no problem throwing it away and starting over.

Comment: Ok, start over by following the instructions in the answer. I slightly modified the answer.

Comment: I think it worked. Apparently I had a .git directory in the project directory's parent that was confusing things (don't know how it got there). One puzzlement: the file misc.xml in the .idea folder didn't get pushed. Any idea why? Is this a problem? Should I do something?

Comment: You don't need to push all files in the .idea directory. It will be generated automatically. If you want to include it, you can open the file .gitignore and remove the files you want to include.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157151/discussion-between-robert-lewis-and-nabin-bhandari).

Answer (score 0):

To copy android studio project to a remote repo, you just need to follow below few steps (for your situation):

#### If the android project already managed in a local git repo

In Android studio Terminal windows, use below commands:

```
git remote add upstream <URL for the remote repo> -f
git push upstream master
```

#### If the android project is not manage in git repo for now, you can use below steps:

In the root directory of your project, execute the following commands,

```
git init
git remote add origin <URL for the remote repo> -f
touch .gitignore
#Add the (pattern of) files you do not want to traced by git, as https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore
git add .
git commit -m 'add .gitignore'
git push origin master
```

**Note:** If the remote git repo is not empty, you can clone the remote repo locally and then copy your project in it. Then commit and push.